# Qt Creator runs clangd many times and the demons don't finish

Tags: qt-creator, clangd

I had left turned on Ubuntu and Qt Creator for a night, next day the htop showed:

[image]

Qt Creator 7.0.0 (GCC 10.3.1 20210422 (Red Hat 10.3.1-1), 64).
Built Mar 22 2022 в 02:18:16.
Revision 638b93591b.

clangd version 14.0.0 (git://code.qt.io/clang/llvm-project.git a8ed6c28965138fa1f2449e4ce3e9f391380d17b)
Features: linux
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

What would you advise in the situation? Thanks.